# Converting Spark UDF written in SCALA to JAVA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is my spark UD, can anyone help me to convert this into java?

```
val customUDF = udf((array: Seq[String]) => {
    val newts = array.filter(_.nonEmpty)
    if  (newts.size == 0) null
    else newts.head
})
```

Comment: Scala is so beautiful..

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```java
UDF2 my_udf = new UDF2<WrappedArray<String>, String>() {
  public String call(WrappedArray<String> arr) throws Exception {
    String[] newts = arr.filter(_.nonEmpty)
    if (newts.length == 0) {
      return null
    } else { newts[0] }
  }
};

spark.udf().register("my_udf", my_udf, DataTypes.StringType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways

1. Inline using Lambda i.e. Scala style
2. Or you can define a method and register it.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF0;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;

import java.util.List;

public class SimpleUDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
        spark.sqlContext()
                .udf()
                .register("sampleUDFLambda", (List<String> array) -> array.stream().filter(element ->
                        !element.isEmpty()).findFirst().orElse(null), DataTypes.StringType);

    }

    //Or you can define a function 

    private UDF1< List<String>,String> sampleUdf()
    {
        return ( array ) -> array.stream().filter(element ->
                !element.isEmpty()).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }




}
```